# error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion in very simple example

Tags: c++, linux, constructor, compilation

although this C++ compiler error has been reported many times, I did not find a solution to my problem. I have two files, Foo.hh:

```
class Serial
{
 public:
  Serial(int portNumber);
  ~Serial();
 private:
  int portNr;
};
```

and Foo.cc:

```
#include "Foo.hh"
Serial::Serial(inx portNumber)
{
  portNr = portNumber;
}
Serial::~Serial()
{
}
```

which I try to compile on Linux using

```
g++ -I. -c -o Foo.o Foo.cc
```

returning the error

```
Foo.cc:4:15: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
```

I do not see any special reason why this should give an error! Any ideas appreciated...

Comment: compiler errors are not always very helpful. However, you should accept the best correct answer!

Comment: When reporting compiler errors, it is good to provide a hint in the form of a comment on the line in the question. Line 4 in your file is probably line 2 in the question's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Misspelled `int` in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `inx` instead of `int` in Foo.cc.

Comment: Perfect, that was it!! Thanks for the quick help...